# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been trying to figure out why this error is happening for a while
I put the tableview in view controller. 
Set the tableview delegate and datasource to view controller.
I have implemented the delegate and datasource protocols.

I have done the same scene in fresh project almost 4 times, It worked fine. When I am trying to implement this scene in my current projects I see this error.

If I remove setting the delegate of table view then everything goes fine.

It is happening after returning cell.

What could be the reason? I am unable to figure it.I am using no arrays too.

[image]

Comment: please show the full code,screenshot is not too helpful, paste all the code involved. also why not using array

Comment: Update your question with relevant code (pasted as text). Point out where the error actually happens.

Comment: The error is most likely due to your datasource and you are not showing that.

Comment: I already used this methods  in other tableview.                                                                                  //-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
So I had to rewrite it in current scene. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index 0 beyond bounds for empty array error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870600/index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use Exception Break points...As per the above answer
make sure if the delegate methods were set in previous scenes of the project.

I used all the below methods:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try adding an all-exception breakpoint (Add Exception Breakpoint) to debug where the exception occures. Maybe it is not even in that viewcontroller.
[image: Add Exception Breakpoint]